# php glob optional characters

Tags: php, regex, glob

My skills are limited in PHP, so I would appreciate any help in the following. In file system, I have a file `5.japan.jpg`, and I would like to match it from a var `japan` without knowing the extension, or if there is a [number.dot] in front of the filename. I got this far:

```
$var = 'japan';
glob($var.'.*');
```

Of course, the above would match `japan.jpg` and `japan.pdf` but not `5.japan.jpg`. Could anyone point me out in the right direction? I need to include files that have any number+dot in front, for example `16.var.jpg` or `1.var.jpg`, but not exclude just `var.jpg`. Thanks!

Comment: `glob('*'.$var.'.*')` should help.

Comment: Well, you can use `*japan.*` obviously. That will give you all matches with _anything_ before the "japan", so you might have to filter that down again later by means of a regex. But that is the best you can do with `glob()`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for help. I ended up using the following

```
glob($path.'/*'.$name.'*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

It is not flawless, as it could end up matching another image that *contains* the var name, but I think it's good enough in my case without having to resort to reading all files in directory before doing a `preg_match`.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the directory listing into an array, you can walk the array and do something like:

```
$string = '5.japan.gif';
$var = 'japan';

$match = preg_match("/^[0-9]*\.{$var}\.([a-z]+)$/", $string);

echo $match;
```

`glob()` seems to provide some limited implementation of regex, so I am not sure you can do that with `glob()` function directly